# Hadoop docker: Cannot connect to resource manager

Tags: docker, hadoop, configuration

I am super new to docker and trying to configure single node hadoop using docker in ubuntu server. Here is what I have already done.

```
$ docker pull sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.7.1
 ......
$ docker run -it sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.7.1 /etc/bootstrap.sh -bash
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
18/06/27 12:59:00 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [cb46e163e0be]
cb46e163e0be: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-namenode-cb46e163e0be.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-datanode-cb46e163e0be.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-secondarynamenode-cb46e163e0be.out
18/06/27 12:59:26 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn--resourcemanager-cb46e163e0be.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-nodemanager-cb46e163e0be.out
bash-4.1# jps
532 ResourceManager
204 DataNode
118 NameNode
371 SecondaryNameNode
918 Jps
620 NodeManager
```

`jps` shows that resource manager is running. Now I tried to test the hadoop

```
bash-4.1# cd $HADOOP_PREFIX
bash-4.1# bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
18/06/27 13:02:23 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/06/27 13:02:25 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
18/06/27 13:02:27 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 31
18/06/27 13:02:27 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:31
18/06/27 13:02:28 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1530118774059_0001
18/06/27 13:02:28 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1530118774059_0001
18/06/27 13:02:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://cb46e163e0be:8088/proxy/application_1530118774059_0001/
18/06/27 13:02:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1530118774059_0001
18/06/27 13:02:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1530118774059_0001 running in uber mode : false
18/06/27 13:02:44 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/06/27 13:05:56 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: cb46e163e0be/172.17.0.2:42698. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/06/27 13:05:57 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: cb46e163e0be/172.17.0.2:42698. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/06/27 13:05:58 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: cb46e163e0be/172.17.0.2:42698. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/06/27 13:05:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: cb46e163e0be/172.17.0.2:42698. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/06/27 13:06:00 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: cb46e163e0be/172.17.0.2:42698. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/06/27 13:06:01 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: cb46e163e0be/172.17.0.2:42698. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
^C
bash-4.1# jps
532 ResourceManager
204 DataNode
1671 Jps
371 SecondaryNameNode

bash-4.1#
```

Now I don't understand 2 things here.

1. This is kind of official image of hadoop so why it is not running correctly? Did I make any mistake? IF yes then what ?
2. When I did `jps` before running the example code you can see `node manager` and `name node` were returned by `jps`. But after running the example and quitting the example, these couple of objects were not returned by `jps`. Why is it so?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: `The url to track the job:`... You can get more information there. Just because services are up doesn't necessarily mean you have resources available for a job to start, they'll only be accepted... And if those services are killed, you need to provide those logs, not your mapreduce job

Comment: I solved the problem to an extent. So I used the hadoop-docker:2.7.0 not 2.7.1 and it worked correctly. I don't the cause of the problem but its working fine now. But still for future viewers of this question, if someone can answer in detail about the above problem, its cause, and possible solution would be great.